# Luggage lockers in Reno

Tags: luggage-storage, nevada

I'll have a 4 hour transfer in Reno, Nevada, United States, from bus to train.
Amtrak report that [the train station has no luggage lockers](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?pagename=am/am2Station/Station_Page&code=RNO).
Greyhound have [no information about the availability of luggage lockers](http://www.greyhound.com/en/locations/terminal.aspx?city=870254).
Is there any luggage locker service at or close to either the Greyhound or the Amtrak station in Reno, Nevada, United States?
If not, what other options do I have for storing luggage for several hours?

Comment: You can check-in your luggage on the train (it's offered at Reno station). But it means you have to leave the train in a station that also offer checking luggage. And it also means you will not need this luggage on board.

Comment: @Vince Although not an answer that's an interesting idea (I do leave the train at a station offering this option).  I suppose it also means I will need some more time before I get my luggage after leaving the train, but that's not a problem.  Certainly an option I will consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has become quite difficult to find left luggage facilities in transportation centers in the U.S., but you can speak to the bell desk at any major hotel and ask them to hold bags for you. In a large hotel, the bell desk will operate more or less independently of the front desk, and not care too much whether you are a guest at the hotel or not.

You should receive a claim check. There is usually no charge; however, you are expected to tip the clerk for retrieving them from storage when you return, a bare minimum of $1 per item ($2 or more in places like New York or Las Vegas).

---

As far as I can tell, the Reno train station no longer accepts left luggage, but as Vince noted in his comment, most long-distance Amtrak trains have a baggage car, and will accept [checked luggage](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/Satellite?SnippetName=IBLegacy&pagename=am/AM_Snippet_C/SnippetWrapper&amen=Baggage). You will not be able to retrieve this bag until you reach your destination, however, so it may not be an answer to your need.